# Python discord bot -- AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'strip'

Tags: python, discord.py

I am developing a Discord Bot using Python. And getting the following error (AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'strip').  Here is my code.

```
import os
import discord
from dotenv import load_dotenv
load_dotenv()
TOKEN = os.getenv('O.......')
GUILD = os.getenv('CodeUP')

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    for guild in client.guilds:
        if guild.name == GUILD:
            break

    print(
        f'{client.user} is connected to the following guild:\n'
        f'{guild.name}(id: {guild.id})'
    )

client.run(TOKEN)
```

Comment: Can you post the full error traceback?

Comment: If you print the `TOKEN` variable, you'll see it's `None`. The `ODMyMTUxN..` key doesn't exist, I think that might be your actual token

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing you're supposed to get as the "token" is the variable name of your bot token stored in the `.env` file, like this!

Contents of `.env` file:

```
BOT_TOKEN=ODMyMTUxNjQ4OTAxMjY3NTA2.YHfnnQ.r_rQ2mmo8HFvaBAl9rry28VM4Nk
```

Token variable in the python file:

```py
TOKEN = os.getenv('BOT_TOKEN')
```

Answer (score 0):

`os.getenv` gets a enviroment variable with the given name. You are using your token as your name. Replace the code with this:

```
TOKEN = os.getenv('DISCORD_TOKEN', 'ODMyMTUxNjQ4OTAxMjY3NTA2.YHfnnQ.r_rQ2mmo8HFvaBAl9rry28VM4Nk')
```

This find an environment variable named `DISCORD_TOKEN`, and if none exists, use `'ODM...'`

I hope this is not your real token you are posting on the internet though, if so make sure to cancel it immediately.

Comment: I have regenerated the code so no problem.